# First year to grow gladiolus and they all seem to be the same colors?

Tags: flowers, perennials

I planted a ton of gladioli this year and each stalk was suppose to be different colors, there were 7 or 8 different colors they could be but for some reason they are all pretty much orange. The first 2 were red. The next 5 are oranga and 1 is purple. Granted that's only half cuz half haven't bloomed yet and I do like the orange but I wanted the array of colprs. Disappointed to say the least. Hoping the other half will be different colors. Could this be something I'm doing wrong? Or is it just the luck of the draw with the aassortment kind? Or maybe the company that sells them have more oranmore I'm not sure. Thanks to any input!

Answer (score 5):

Have patience, at least two weeks. In my collection there is a definite order of appearance from corms planted all at the same time, and my 5 colours go: orange, lavender, crimson, white, scarlet with about 10 days or so between first appearances of orange and scarlet. Under free self propagation in my soil orange tends to reproduce itself most freely through corm division and cormlets.

Corm size when planted also seems to be a factor. Less than 1cm and they might not bloom at all; the larger corms will likely be in flower first, all other things being equal. Reasoning here is that the smaller fry need to bulk up before they have the strength to send up a flower spike.